# How to deal with the record/row boundary of splittable lzo files in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have some lzo compressed files output by MapReduce, and they will be used in another job. All these files are indexed and I have set LzoTextInputFormat as inputformat class.

My question is:

When using these lzo files, how to deal with the record/row boundary?

A record/row may be truncated into two adjacent compression blocks. If the tow adjacent blocks are logically splited into different Mappers, it is difficult to determine the incomplete record/row and combine the two parts.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SequenceFile. SequenceFile writes compressed blocks with synchronization marks. As result, seqfiles are splittable.